# System.ArgumentException : Type of member 'WebElement' is not IWebElement or IList<IWebElement>

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

There is a radio button and I tried using IList<IWebElement> and/or IWebElement and/or WebElement.
Still I am getting the below exception:

```
System.ArgumentException : Type of member 'WebElement' is not IWebElement or IList\<IWebElement\>

Message: 
System.ArgumentException : Type of member 'WebElement' is not IWebElement or IList\<IWebElement\>

`Stack Trace:  DefaultPageObjectMemberDecorator.CreateObject(Type memberType, IElementLocator locator, IEnumerable`1 bys, Boolean cache)

DefaultPageObjectMemberDecorator.Decorate(MemberInfo member, IElementLocator locator)
PageFactory.InitElements(Object page, IElementLocator locator, IPageObjectMemberDecorator decorator)
PageFactory.InitElements(Object page, IElementLocator locator)
PageFactory.InitElements(ISearchContext driver, Object page)

Page.GetPage[T]() line 15

Page.get_OPSChangeTypeDeclarationPage() line 185

OPSChageApplicationStepDefinitions.ThenIAmRedirectedToAPageHavingAllTheChangeTypes() line 45

BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object\[\] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object\[\] arguments, TimeSpan& duration)
TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance)
TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
OPSChageApplicationFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
OPSChageApplicationFeature.ApplyToMakeChangesToPermit(String userName, String password, String permitNumber, String changeTypeName, String changeTypeValue, String desiredChange, String\[\] exampleTags) line 28
```

[I am trying to click the radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgW01.jpg)`

```
namespace Rapid.Pages
{
    public class OPSChangeTypeDeclarationPage
    {
        //Page heading
        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//span[contains(@id,'applyPermit_label')]")]
        [CacheLookup]
        public WebElement OPSChangeTypeDeclarationPgTitle { get; set; }
        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//a[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_btnContinue']")]
        public WebElement OPSChangeTypeContinueBtn { get; set; }

        //List of change type - radio buttons
        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[@type='radio']")]
        [CacheLookup]
        public IList<IWebElement> OPSChangeTypeRBList { get; set; }

        // Resusable Explicit Wait
        public WebDriverWait WaitFor20Sec => new WebDriverWait(Browser.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

        //Methods related to this page
        public string GetTitleOfChangeTypeDeclarationPg()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            WaitFor20Sec.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(OPSChangeTypeDeclarationPgTitle));
            return OPSChangeTypeDeclarationPgTitle.Text;


        }
       public void SelectChangeTypeForPermitRecord(string lChangeTypeValue)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            int Size = OPSChangeTypeRBList.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
            {
                String CurrentValue = OPSChangeTypeRBList.ElementAt(i).GetAttribute("value");
                if (CurrentValue.Equals(lChangeTypeValue))
                {
                    OPSChangeTypeRBList.ElementAt(i).Click();
                    break;
                }//end of if
            }//end of for loop

            Thread.Sleep(200);
            OPSChangeTypeContinueBtn.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }


    }//end of class
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: Error mgs is thrown while Initialising the page and its elements/locators

Answer (score -1):

This issue is resolved!! Above mentioned webelements are refactored as "IWebElement".